# How to align Nav.Link equal width in React Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to align Nav.Link components equal width.

```
      <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" fixed="bottom">
          <Nav  className="me-auto">
            <Container>
              <Row>
                <Col>
                  <Nav.Link href="#search"></Nav.Link>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                  <Nav.Link href="#start-a-thread">➕</Nav.Link>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Container>
          </Nav>
      </Navbar>
```

But they're rendered on the left like this.

[image: result]

I think each `Col` components are rendered equal width with reference to [Auto-layout columns](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns), but they aren't.

### Environment

- MacOS 13.0
- Node.js 18.11.0
- React 18.2.0
- React Bootstrap 2.5.0
- Google Chrome 107.0.5304.87

Thank you to read. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The React-Bootstrap doesnt much depend on the bootstrap but it tends to take the styles from the Bootstrap and you need include the styles using either

```
{/* The following line can be included in your src/index.js or App.js file */}

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

or using the CDN

```
<link
rel="stylesheet"
href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384- 
Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi"
crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```

Comment: Thank you. I already include ```import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';``` in src/index.tsx, and tentatively added the same line in BBSNav.tsx (the file in the question), but the result doesn't change.